# Joining Two table with three ON

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, toad

im trying to slect data from two tables with out primary key
now my question is what im doing wrong in my joning ,can i use more than 1 ON in joining table.

```
SELECT 
    A.PRODUCT, 
   A.WSTYPE, A.PACKAGE, AWACSLF.LFSIZE,AWACSLF.DEFAULTWOQTY
FROM OCAPSYS.AWACSRECIPEBYWSTYPE A
 inner join  OCAPSYS.AWACSLF 
 On A.LEADFRAME12NC = AWACSLF.LF12NC  
 On A.PRODUCT =  AWACSLF.DEVICE
 On A.PACKAGE =  AWACSLF.PACKAGE
```

Comment: There can be only one `ON` and other two `ON` should be changed to `AND`. So it changes to `On A.LEADFRAME12NC = AWACSLF.LF12NC  AND A.PRODUCT =  AWACSLF.DEVICE AND A.PACKAGE =  AWACSLF.PACKAGE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper syntax is to use `AND`:

```
   SELECT 
       A.PRODUCT, 
       A.WSTYPE, A.PACKAGE, AWACSLF.LFSIZE,AWACSLF.DEFAULTWOQTY
       FROM OCAPSYS.AWACSRECIPEBYWSTYPE A
       INNER JOIN  OCAPSYS.AWACSLF 
       ON A.LEADFRAME12NC = AWACSLF.LF12NC  
       AND A.PRODUCT =  AWACSLF.DEVICE
       AND A.PACKAGE =  AWACSLF.PACKAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple ON as long as the data of each tables doesn't have the same column name. But ON is only use for tables only. For example:

```
SELECT O.OrderNumber, CONVERT(date,O.OrderDate) AS Date, 
       P.ProductName, I.Quantity, I.UnitPrice 
  FROM [Order] O 
  JOIN OrderItem I ON O.Id = I.OrderId 
  JOIN Product P ON P.Id = I.ProductId
ORDER BY O.OrderNumber
```

What are you really aiming to do about the data? To make it array of an array? Or just array?